# WCF hosting and Performance

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, performance, iis

I have WCF service. I have done some testing with basichttp binding and tcp binding.

In a console client i created hundreds of threads and hit the service with tcp and http binding. Turned out TCP is twice faster than http.

Then i made a web client that runs on IIS and hits the service.
Turned out that http is faster then TCP.

How does this happen? isnt TCP supposed to be faster than basichttp? COde is like the one below. similar.

```
stopwatch start here

Thread[] ts = new Thread[100];  
for(int i= 0; i< ts.lenght;i++){  
  ts[i] = new Thread(foo);  // replace with bar for the second test.
  ts[i].start();  
}

for(int i 0;i< ts.lenght;i++){  
  ts[i].join();  
}  

stopwatch stop here.

public static void foo(){  
MyServiceClient myclient = new MyServiceClient("netTcpBinding");  
myclient.GetResult(1);  
} 

public static void bar(){
MyServiceClient myclient = new MyServiceClient("basicHttpBinding");
myclient.GetResult(1);
}
```

Comment: It depends on code of your tests.

Comment: Is your second test running on the same machine as the service?

Comment: they are identical code. I m just invoking one service method with both configuration. Only difference is the binding.

Comment: yes, both are running on the same machine. only difference is binding. eg: Client c = new Client("bindingTCPorHTTP"); c.invokeMethod();

Comment: Loosely, NetNamedPipe is for when the client/server are on the same machine.  NetTcp when they're on the same network.  Http when they're communicating through the internet.  Check this thread for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765692/wcf-net-pipe-vs-net-tcp-vs-http-bindings

Comment: @epalm: That wasnt my question. i already know that.

Comment: do you have any caching happening on the IIS side?

Comment: Edited with the test code. It s not the exact code, but this is the idea.

Comment: Also, do you have any caching going on at your web client?  You probably do if you are using a real web browser.

Comment: No caching on the web client.

Comment: What about caching on the web server side?

Comment: no cachin on server side or client side. just pure method calls. nada.

Comment: Out of interest, has the OP tried benchmarking the same tcp WCF hosted in a windows service endpoint rather than iis7?

Comment: You really need to post your binding configs here or at least state that you are using the defaults. There are many knobs and switches for the bindings and they're different per binding type. So it's very hard to tell you what might be happening without knowing all those details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you know that WCF has throttling turned on *by default*. Before you run these tests, you should turn it off by using this bit of config in your web.config's serviceModel section:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior> <!-- can omit name in .NET 4 -->
      <serviceThrottling 
        maxConcurrentCalls="10000" 
        maxConcurrentSessions="100000" 
        maxConcurrentInstances="100000" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The defaults vary by version but are around 16, 10, 100 or something along those lines in .NET 4. Those lower defaults are applied *even if you have no throttling entry* in your web.config / app.config.

Good luck.

Comment: In .NET 4.0 they are dependent on the `ProcessorCount` of your system so that the throttling limits are automatically scaled according to the capabilities of the machine the service is running on. For more information, see [WCF 4: Higher Default Throttling Settings for WCF Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that of the *hosting process*.  .NET defaults to a certain number of **worker threads** in the *thread pool* which can be overridden by the process prior to creation of thread tasks.  considering your second test is in *IIS*, which prior to WCF4 in conjunction with *AppFabric* defaults to HTTP, IIS due to the nature of the beast could quite possibly be changing the default number of worker threads.

just because you ask for say 100 threads on any given machine, does not mean all will be created at once but rather queued not to mention limitations of thread context switching.

as a general rule you should not create more worker threads than the number of cores on the machine.

Comment: This is true. You can do things like ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(), etc. But be aware that WCF imposes throttling limits on top of this restriction.