# Regarding the scenarios of protocol usage in WCF

Tags: wcf, http, tcp, msmq, named-pipes

WCF supports various protocols like TCP, HTTP, HTTPS, Named Pipes, MSMQ.

Please can you provide scenarios based on which the developer will choose an appropriate protocol when developing the WCF service project?

Also, can we have more than 1 protocol in the same web service project? Please can you give an example scenario.

Comment: Yes you can have all of them by some config as you can see [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30828/Host-your-WCF-service-with-multiple-host-environme)

Answer (score 0):

you can have all protocols with little config in the `web.config` file. also you can have soap and restful interface both together. here you can find out more about the various protocols in wcf:
[WCF - net.pipe vs. net.tcp vs. http Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765692/wcf-net-pipe-vs-net-tcp-vs-http-bindings)